# getting this error when I pass **context** in model class in the flutter -

Tags: flutter, dialog

Getting this error when I pass Context in model class in the flutter -

> Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/localizations.dart':
>
> Failed assertion:  'Context != null': is not true.

```
MessageDialog(context, UtilString.logOut, UtilString.logOutMessage,UtilString.logOut,MessageDialogActionHandler(context,this,null));
```

The context passed as local field or global but getting all time this error.

```
var _responseBody = jsonDecode(_response.body); 
if (_responseBody[APIKey.SUCCESS]) { 
listener.onSuccess(token,_responseBody[APIKey.PAYDATE]); //todo to show success dialog - 
MessageDialog(context, UtilString.logOut, UtilString.logOutMessage, UtilString.logOut,MessageDialogActionHandler(context,this,null));
print("success" + APIKey.SUCCESS); 
print("api second"); 
} else{
 listener.isFailed(_responseBody[APIKey.MESSAGE]);
}
```

Comment: Please add some code of what you are trying

Comment: @Android_id please check above code